# Swap out 3 differently-sized logos with media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to have 3 different logo sizes (`small`, `med`, `big`) based on different screen sizes.  Here's my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 487px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_small.png") !important; 
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_med.png") !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_big.png") !important;
  }
}
```

This works swapping from `big` to `med`, but it won't swap again from `med` to `small`.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the min-width on the second media query also. Even when the screen is small the second query is true and the last css gets preference so its loading the second query image.
Make the following change.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 487px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_small.png") !important; 
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 487px) and (max-width: 1079px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_med.png") !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .site-header .site-branding {
    background-image: url("../images/logo_big.png") !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order it like this:

### CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    .site-header .site-branding {
        background-image: url("../images/logo_big.png") !important;
        background: blue;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1079px) {
    .site-header .site-branding {
        background-image: url("../images/logo_med.png") !important;
        background: green;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 487px) {
    .site-header .site-branding {
        background-image: url("../images/logo_small.png") !important;
        background: red;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/byH2j/)

Answer (score 1):

See: http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ under 'Overriding'.

I think what is happening is both the first and second media queries are true, so the second one is overriding the first; thus, never reaching the point to switch to small.

Solution: move the first media query to be the final one... should fix it and adjust accordingly.