# Double logo in wordpress site identity?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need double logo in site identity of WordPress customizer. One on mobile view and other on desktop view. Both are different images. Please provide code for adding two logos.
I have code for adding one custom logo. and I need it on site identity itself

```
function lotus_flies_custom_logo_setup()
{
    $defaults = array(
        'height'      => 139,
        'width'       => 176,
        // 'flex-height' => true,
        // 'flex-width'  => true,
        'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
    );
    add_theme_support('custom-logo', $defaults);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lotus_flies_custom_logo_setup');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have different logo according to screen size is to use @media queries in CSS.

So you could just find out a css selector for your current icon, and add some css to resize it according to screen size, in your inherited custom template.
Instead of resizing, you could also just completely change the source of the image in CSS.

( As an inspiration: [Swap out 3 differently-sized logos with media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400065/swap-out-3-differently-sized-logos-with-media-queries) . Documentation: [Using_media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) )

Comment: @Asheeka, for your information: there is a website from stackexchange especially dedicated for wordpress: wordpress.stackexchange.com